# Transferring Data Between Pages on a Website

Tags: javascript, mysql, cookies

What is the best way to transfer data from page to page on a website? For instance, I'm logged into this site and stay logged in know matter how many times I switch pages and even if I close the browser. How exactly is this done? I'm thinking through the use of cookies, but I"m really not sure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options Cookies and Sessions

Rule of thumb: do not trust user input. Cookies are user input, session ids that are stored in cookies are user input, http headers are user input -- these things must be triple checked for every possible thing. Session data, on the other hand, is stored on your server, so it is more or less secure if not stored in /tmp.

One of the most popular setups for session authorization is this: session id is stored in cookie, and everything else including password is stored in session. After starting a session based on id from a cookie, you should get user id from session data and then check if password stored there is still valid.

If you set a session variable, the user can't directly change it unless they hijack another session cookie.

What you mainly have to watch out for is on shared hosting, your session data isn't secure (typically other sites can see it).

It's also worth noting that cookie data isn't secure either. It shouldn't be relied upon in the same way that form data shouldn't be relied upon (no matter what client validation tells you).

Your best practices with passwords are:

- Store the password in the database in a hashed form, preferably SHA1 (first choice) or MD5 (second choice);
- When you receive the user's password, encrypt it and check it against what's stored in the database;
- Set the logged in username in the user session;
- Expire the cookie after some period (even if its days) rather than having it last forever; and
- Use a secure connection (HTTPS not HTTP) where possible. SSL certificates are cheap.

Comment: I think I understand it. So I would: 

-> Have the user login.
-> When they login store their username in a session.
-> Store the session in a cookie with an expiration.
-> As I'm going from page to page, access the cookie, and session to  obtain user information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you stay logged in typically because there is a cookie which stores your session ID.